# AWS ALB health check failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, aws-application-load-balancer, health-check

I have created an AWS EC2 instance and running a jenkins container inside it,
Here are the details :

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                      COMMAND  CREATED       STATUS           PORTS                                             NAMES
xxxxxxxxx  docker.io/jenkins/jenkins           47 hours ago  Up 47 hours ago  0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp  jenkins
```

after that I have configured an AWS ALB to listen on port 443 and given this jenkins instance running jenkins container as target.

The loadbalancer health check details are as below:
[image]

I have tried with traffic port aswell, but that also showd unhealthy.

after this my loadbalancer is able to forward request to the instance and I am able to reach jenkins container with the loadbalancer dns.

But my **Loadbalancer is showing my target as unhealthy**,
[image]

Can some one help me why my target is not healthy and what steps i could do to make it healthy.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins EC2 should be assigned a security group that allows access on the Jenkins port (8080) from the ALB. and you’ll provide full outbound internet access to Jenkins in order that updates and plugins can be installed.

The Jenkins requires authentication, so when the ALB is doing its health check as an anonymous user it gets a 403 access forbidden page, but http health check expect 200 ok code, so You can switch this to a tcp health check.

Comment: my jenkins instance already allow port 8080 from anywhere and outbound rules are also configured for everywhere.

Comment: Its an Application load balancer , ALB operates on layer 7 na, It will work on http/https only. tcp health check cannot be configured

Comment: Could you try 403 as success code instead of 200

Comment: but thats just a work around right? giving 403 code as status ok doesnt seem like a perfect solution, that doesnt sums up why loadbalancer was getting 403 error

Comment: You aren't "giving 403 as status OK". That isn't a status code that a user will ever see. `403` just means "the server is up, but it requires a login". All you care about there for health check reasons is "the server is up". So changing success code to 403 in the health check is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use /login instead of /
Verify the port no also. I am using 8080

Answer (score 0):

I created a Jenkins container on Fargate ECS and it was giving me this error when I tried to configure an ALB to it.
`service jenkins-alb (port 8080) is unhealthy in target-group ecs-demo2-jenkins-alb due to (reason Health checks failed with these codes: [403]).`

I found the solution that when the ALB healthcheck tries to go to the target group, it is greeted with the jenkins login page and requires authorization which is why the healthcheck fails with error 403. The workaround I used for this was to change the healthcheck path from '/' to '/login?from=%2F' and it worked!